# Is the OT unveiled in the entire NT or just the Gospels?

Tags: catholicism, augustine

St. Augustine Sayeth:

> the New Testament lies hidden in the Old and the Old Testament is unveiled in the New.

(paraphrased quote from the Catechism)

Just for context, I looked this up and he actually said

> Wherefore, in the Old Testament there is a veiling of the New, and in the New Testament there is a revealing of the Old.

[source](http://www.newadvent.org/fathers/1303.htm)

We believe this in Catholicism and it's apparent from the way we structure the readings at Mass, the OT reading is always subtly explaining the Gospel one.  But is that the case, is it just the Gospel (+Acts?) that is hidden in the OT.  How do the epistles and revelation work in to the "hidden in / unveiled" equation?

Answer (score 6):

I think the whole NT reveals the old, particularly in explaining OT prophecy. Possible the best example is the [Book of Hebrews](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Hebrews+1&version=NIV1984), since it may well have been written for *exactly that purpose*. Some examples:

> To which of the angels did God ever say,
>
> "Sit at my right hand
>
> until I make your enemies
>
> a footstool for your feet"

[Hebrews 1:13](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Hebrews%201:13&version=NIV1984), quoting [Psalm 110:1](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Psalm%20110:1&version=NIV1984).

Then there is the account of [Melchizedek](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Genesis%2014:18&version=NIV1984) in [Hebrews 7](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Hebrews+7&version=NIV1984), who as both **King** and **Priest** was an archetype of Christ. (This theme is carried on into subsequent chapters, the High Priest in [chapter 8](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Hebrews+8&version=NIV1984) and the Blood of a sacrifice (Christ in NT) in [chapters 9](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Hebrews+9&version=NIV1984) and [10](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Hebrews+10&version=NIV1984).)

Finally (in this *very* brief overview of Hebrews), is the men and women of faith in [chapter 11](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Hebrews+11&version=NIV1984).

That's just one book!

Other examples I could mention are the imaginary of [Ezekiel](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Ezekiel+1&version=NIV1984) and [Daniel](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Daniel+1&version=NIV1984) coming back in [Revelation](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Revelation+1&version=NIV1984), Paul explaining grace in [Galatians 4:21-31](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Galatians%204:21-31&version=NIV1984) using the examples of Hagar and Sarah and Peter quoting proverbs in [2 Peter 2:22](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=2%20Peter%202:22&version=NIV1984).

Finally (for my summary, there is of course *much* more), there is the promise of a New Heaven and a New Earth, first revealed in Isaiah [65:17](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Isaiah+65:17&version=NIV1984) and [66:22](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Isaiah+66:22&version=NIV1984) and then repeated by Peter in [2 Peter 3:13](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=2%20Peter+3:13&version=NIV1984) and John in [Revelation 21:1](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Revelation+21:1&version=NIV1984).

So, yes, the OT comes back time and time again in the NT. One might speculate it was planned that way. :)

Comment: Christ is constantly making reference to the books of Moses and the prophecies pointing out that He is the fulfillment of everything toward which the Old Testament was pointing.  The Epistles, especially those of St. Paul (who, as a Pharisee, knew the Scriptures very well) also constantly makes reference to the Old Testament, as though to remind the Jews of the prophecies and how they are fulfilled in Christ.